# Blackberry SenderDestination context significance

Tags: json, blackberry

I'm writing code to fetch JSON and I wanted to know the significance of context in the `SenderDestination` constructors as follows:

```
BlockingSenderDestination bsd = (BlockingSenderDestination) DestinationFactory.getSenderDestination("context_string", URI.create(uriStr));
```

Comment: i recommend to use the old style http classes, we had a lot of trouble with the new api, memory leaks and improper context handling (on BB 7 beta devices at least)

Comment: Thanks...I was trying to fetch Json using `BlockingSenderDestination` but was unable to(hence the question). Now I've implemented this J2ME style!